# How to query to get multiple records for specific ids using limit

Tags: mysql

I have a field in my table called `iciphers_id`. Each `iciphers_id` has multiple records in that table.

I want to get records for some specific `iciphers_id`. This below query gets all records for following ids.

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE iciphers_id IN (200,201,202)
```

I want to write query to get all records for those specific `iciphers_id` but 10 records for each `iciphers_id`. I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE iciphers_id IN (200,201,202) LIMIT 10.
```

This above query returns only 10 records, I want to get 10 records for each `iciphers_id` which is 200,201,202.

Note: I have just added three `iciphers_id` in above query, They can more than that (hundreds).

Iciphers id can be more than hundred. Maybe i should use between in query like `where iciphers_id >= 200 AND Iciphers_id <= 300`

Comment: Can  be more than 3 or will be more than 3? What decides this? is it different everything, is it incremental etc?

Comment: @Asfandyar Khan how many records will be exist per `iciphers_id` in a table ?

Comment: They can be multiple, between 10 to 100,000 for a single `iciphers_id`

Answer (score -1):

You may try it.

```
SELECT * 
   FROM
     (SELECT * , 
                  @iciphers_id_rank := IF(@current_iciphers_id = iciphers_id, @iciphers_id_rank + 1, 1) AS iciphers_id_rank,
                  @current_iciphers_id := iciphers_id 
       FROM MYTABLE WHERE iciphers_id IN (200,201,202)
       ORDER BY iciphers_id ASC
     ) temp
   WHERE iciphers_id_rank >= 1 AND iciphers_id_rank <= 10 ;
```

Comment: i updated the answer  and you can try now , I think it will be work as you required

Comment: Its not working again, it is returning 50,000+ records, before it was returning 100k+ records. I want my query to return only 30 records for above 3 iciphers_id

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
    -- ids.iciphers_id, -- this is not necessary
    TT.*
from
    (   select distinct iciphers_id
        from MYTABLE
        where iciphers_id > 200 and iciphers_id < 300
    ) ids
    cross apply
    (
        select MT.*
        from MYTABLE MT
        where MT.iciphers_id = ids.iciphers_id
        limit 10
    ) TT
```

Comment: Try to put "limit 10' after where clasue and delete 'top 10'

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; near  `cross apply` in the query...

Comment: please tell us what are you using, sql server? postgresql?

Comment: im using mysql server